# Versioned dependencies

Tags: pdftex, luatex, packages, document-classes, git

I created my own class and style files and have them in my `$HOME/texmf/tex/latex/local/` directory. They form the basis for all my documents. The problem is, these style files are changing often, as I just started to develop them. Hence, the document I am working on, always compiles, but the older documents either do not compile or the result is not as before.

I have `$HOME/texmf/tex/latex/local/` in a git repository, so the obvious thing to do, would to include these files as a sub-repository in every document. Each document would have their version of the style files pinned.

The structure would be like

```
~/docs/mycurrentdoc/main.tex
~/docs/mycurrentdoc/texmf/tex/latex/local/
```

How can I tell (lua)latex to use the style files under `~/docs/mycurrentdoc/texmf/tex/latex/local/` for `~/docs/mycurrentdoc/main.tex`?

Comment: did you try using the relative path `\documentclass{texmf/tex/latex/local/mystile}` ?

Comment: Something like `cd ~/docs/mycurrentdoc ; TEXMFHOME=./texmf lualatex main.tex` (untested).

Comment: @EladDen There are around 10 sty files which are referring each other.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I am using TexStudio to write. It would be great if I could get it working there.

Comment: Alternatively, you could symlink your desired style file to the directory with `main.tex` in it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem @ManuelSchmidt. Manage the style files wherever you want to and call them in the main.tex using relative paths. Why is that not working?

Comment: @EladDen ATM I have many style files which just include each other. If this is the easiest solution, I change all of them to use relative paths.